# jasper report - decreasing width of fields results in lesser number of rows

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report which has 12 columns. 10 of these columns were defined with width 160 and other 2 with width 480. While the report could be opened in PDF and excel successfully, it could not export in docx. I decreased the width. Made each field as 100 and bigger 2 as 200. But very shockingly this has resulted in lesser number of rows being resulted. This is completely baffling to me. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Its probably wrapping the text (hence shorter columns, text  goes to new line, record take more space...)  being resulted?.. what means? I interpreted as less rows on page... do you mean rows missing??

Comment: Missing rows is what I meant. Sorry for not explaining earlier. Number of rows in excel decreased from 1100+ to somewhere around 900.

Comment: This seems very strange... can you post some relevant jrxml code, surely some other issue than column size.. isPrintRepeatedValues="false"

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I found out there were lesser number of rows in excel but in PDF I could see blank rows. Culprit was 'Position Type' set to 'Fix Relative to Bottom' and 'Stretch Type' set to 'Relative to Tallest Object'. Changing these two settings fixed the issue. It was missing rows in excel which completely took me by surprise. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Great : ) ...consider posting answer (accept it) or delete question... so that this can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Position Type' set to 'Fix Relative to Bottom' and 'Stretch Type' set to 'Relative to Tallest Object'. Changing these two settings fixed the issue.